# Why my function isn't executing i++?

Tags: c++, string, object, for-loop

I am writing a get function within a class of an object oriented program, but the `i++` in my code is not executing for some reason.

This is what is used in my .cpp file:

```
char MyString::Get(int i)
{
  if( i = '\0')
  {
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    return String[i];
  }
}
```

This is what is called in the main.cpp file:

```
for(int i=0; i < String1.Length()+1; i++) 
{
  cout<< String1.Get(i)<<" ";
}

cout << endl;
```

This is the length method in the .cpp file for reference purposes:

```
int MyString::Length()
{
  int counter(0);

  while(String[counter] != '\0')
  {
    counter ++;
  }

  return (counter);
}
```

Also: String1 = Jello World

The output:

> J J J J J J J J J J J J J

Comment: `if (i = '\0') exit(1);` Might want to rethink that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well - probably cause of this.  You assigned instead of compared.  You assigned zero to i. That failed the 'if' test (it's zero), so exit did not get called and the rest of your routine ran with i == to zero.

```
   if( i = '\0')
   {
       exit(1);
   }
```

Comment: Beyond that, `if (i == '\0')` is comparing an integer to a character literal.  This probably isn't what you intended to do.  Re-think what you're trying to do here very carefully.

Comment: The reason I had exit(1); was because of this: The MyString object should contain a Get(...) method that returns the i-th character of the string. If index i out of bound, then program should exit(1). This was written in our instructions, but did I do this wrong or did my professor make a goof?

Comment: Oh Oh! Should I have instead did if(String[i] = '\0')

Comment: I've figured it out!! Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really shown enough code for someone to be able to figure out what your code is doing, but this looks incorrect:

```
  if( i = '\0')
```

a single `=` symbol causes `i` to be assigned the value on the right-hand-side of the expression.
`if( '\0' )` evaluates to `if(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're doing an assignment instead of a comparison, so the "comparison" will always be treated as false -- the result of a comparison is the assigned value, which in this case is 0.

Though it has never become overwhelmingly popular, there is a fairly simple technique to avoid this problem: when you're comparing to a constant, always put the constant on the left. This way, if you mis-type `==` as `=`, the code won't compile:

```
 if ('\0' = i)   // error: lvalue required (or something on that order).
```

Comment: Though this avoids the errors, it makes the code confusing,  Instead, I recommend turning warnings up, and paying attention to them.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I've never had a problem with confusion, but I have used compilers that didn't warn about this, no matter how far you turned up the warnings...